# Does increasing contractility increase LV ESP?

Tags: physiology, cardiology

I see many PV diagrams showing a negligible difference in the ESP when contractility increases. I'm wondering why this is the case, because if more blood is being pumped out into the aorta, the MAP should increase, which should subsequently increase the ESP.

Comment: LV, ESP, MAP, PV? Well I do know what ESP means — Extra-sensory perception, which is presumably what is needed to understand the question.

Comment: LV = left ventricle, ESP = end systolic pressure, MAP = mean arterial pressure, PV = pressure-volume

Comment: Then edit the question to make it intelligible, especially the title. You might also give an example (with source) of the type of diagram you are referring to. The purpose of comments is to suggest improvements or clarification of questions, not for a dialogue.